# Fitting a flue for bungalow

Tags: fireplace

My dad has asked me to fit a flue for his wood burner, he has a bungalow. 
He has purchased some ducting, which I'm not sure is suitable for the job, he also has **not** purchased a top piece to connect it to the chimney pot. According to him you can just leave it 'floating'...

I'm going to assume the answer will be 'don't do it the house will burn down' but at least I can show that to him so he doesn't go ahead with it!

So I have two questions,

**1. Can the ducting be used for a wood burner?**
[image]
[image]

**2. How can I attach it to the top without a 'top', or can I leave it just floating? I seems dangerous to me.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ventillation ducting does not have the ability to withstand the high temperatures encountered with a wood burning stove. This will melt well before the proper stainless steel liner material that should be used starts to turn color leaving aluminum puddles and a disconnected stove freely venting into the living space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least the building is brick.

No, this is not remotely suitable for a solid fuel burning appliance. As the label indicates, it's for ventilation, exhaust hood, or tumble-dryer - and would appear to be aluminum. It will burn through in short order if used on a wood burning stove.

Comment: Thank you I'll show him your answer and hopefully he will listen!